# If a function $ f(x) $ depends only on $ |x| $ then its Fourier transform depends only on $ |w| $

Tags: fourier-analysis

Let $ f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^3,\mathbb{C} ) $ be a function such that for $ x_1,x_2\in \mathbb{R}^3 $ such that   $ |x_{1}|=|x_{2}| $ we have $ f\left(x_{1}\right)=f\left(x_{2}\right) $.

I have to prove that also for any $ \omega_{1},\omega_{2}\in\mathbb{R}^{3} $ we have $ \mathcal{F}\left\{ f\right\} \left(\omega_{1}\right)=\mathcal{F}\left\{ f\right\} \left(\omega_{2}\right) $.

Here's what I have tried:

Note that $ \mathcal{F}\left\{ f\right\} \left(\omega\right)=\frac{1}{\left(2\pi\right)^{3}}\intop_{\mathbb{R}^{3}}f\left(x\right)e^{-i\omega\cdot x}dx $

(where $ \omega \cdot x $ is the dot product of 3dimensional vectors).

Now I want to switch to spherical cooredinates, so I'll note

$ \omega=\left(R\sin\left(\theta_{1}\right)\cos\left(\varphi_{1}\right),R\sin\left(\theta_{1}\right)\sin\left(\varphi_{1}\right),R\cos\left(\theta_{1}\right)\right) $

and $ x=\left(r\sin\left(\theta\right)\cos\left(\varphi\right),r\sin\left(\theta\right)\sin\left(\varphi\right),r\cos\left(\theta\right)\right) $

So that $ \mathcal{F}\left\{ f\right\} \left(\omega\right)=\frac{1}{\left(2\pi\right)^{3}}\intop_{0}^{\infty}\intop_{0}^{\pi}\intop_{0}^{2\pi}f\left(r,\theta,\varphi\right)e^{-irR\left(\sin\theta_{1}\cos\varphi_{1}\sin\theta\cos\theta+\sin\theta_{1}\sin\varphi_{1}\sin\theta\sin\varphi+\cos\theta_{1}\cos\theta\right)}r^{2}\sin\theta d\varphi d\theta dr $

and since $ r $ is radial I can just write $ f(r) $. Also I will use trigonometric identities to get:

$ =\frac{1}{\left(2\pi\right)^{3}}\intop_{0}^{\infty}\intop_{0}^{\pi}\intop_{0}^{2\pi}f\left(r\right)e^{-irR\left(\sin\theta_{1}\sin\theta\cos\left(\varphi-\varphi_{1}\right)+\cos\theta_{1}\cos\theta\right)}r^{2}\sin\theta d\varphi d\theta dr $

All I have to do is to show that the integral does not depend on $ \theta_1 , \varphi_1 $

But I got stuck here. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: HINT https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3614430/8157

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I know I have to change the variables in some way, I already proved it succesfully in $\mathbb{R}^2 $ but Im having trouble with $ \mathbb{R}^3$

Comment: Why not take a derivative and prove those integrals vanish?

Comment: @Ninad Munshi I didnt think about it, sounds like a great idea. Thanks